# Change Whole number to a decimal in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

How do I change a whole number that is a DT_R8 in SSIS to a decimal number? I have some that have decimals and some that dont in my excel spreadsheet that I'm converting. 
For example I may have the following:

```
8512
8134.5
8003.27
7964.97
7250
```

Id like for them to all read this:

```
8512.00
8134.50
8003.27
7964.97
7250.00
```

Ive tried using `DT_DECIMAL,2` in my derived column but it doesn't seem to work. I have it as follows: `(DT_DECIMAL,2)((DT_DECIMAL,2)[Debit Amt])`

Thanks

Comment: What are you getting as a result or what error are you getting?

Comment: @HLGEM Hello, when i run the query i do not get all the numerics with a decimal. I get the results of the original file, 8512, however i want to change it to 8512.00. Some have no decimal, some have part of a decimal (example: 1234.5, but it needs to be 1234.50) and some have the decimal set correctly. I am not getting an error just the convert isnt working the way I need it too.

Comment: ((DT_DECIMAL,2)[Debit Amt] * 1.000001) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, your input and output is an Excel spreadsheet.

From: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683.aspx

> Data types. The Excel driver
>   recognizes only a limited set of data
>   types. For example, all numeric
>   columns are interpreted as doubles
>   (DT_R8), and all string columns (other
>   than memo columns) are interpreted as
>   255-character Unicode strings
>   (DT_WSTR). Integration Services maps
>   the Excel data types as follows:
>
> Numeric – double-precision float
>   (DT_R8)

So, I think the only solution is to save it like a string in the spreadsheet, concatenating as many zeros as needed on the right. Here is the code for the derived column with a precision of 3 decimals.

```
FINDSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Debit Amt],",",1) == 0 ? (DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Debit Amt] + ",000" : (DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Debit Amt] + REPLICATE("0",4 - LEN(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Debit Amt],FINDSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Debit Amt],",",1),LEN((DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DECIMAL,3)[Debit Amt]))))
```